# Can I install Ubuntu On My Raspberry pie?

Tags: networking, server, ftp

How can i Install the ubuntu oparating system on my new raspberry Pie? I don't know that if i use a 512 GB memory disk on raspberry and try to install ubuntu then Could i get successes or not?

I want to run an ftp server on that raspberry pie, So which softwere Is work perfect for me. Basically i think that for installing a server box to control my ftp [mojaloss server](https://bmdays.com/mojaloss/) with ubuntu oparating system.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend checking out this: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi. They provide some excellent resources and the instructions are pretty easy to follow.

You do need to make some choices -- like whether you want your Pi to run as a pure server or as desktop. But other than that you should be well on your way.